# What do you call a dripping liquid?

Tags: word-request

What do you call a dripping liquid? When you salivate, sometimes there's dripping liquid hanging from your mouth or chin. What do you call it? Is there a word for it?

> There was a dangling ___ of saliva hanging from her chin.
>
> There was a dangling ___ hanging from her chin.

Answer (score 2):

You might be interested in *drool*:

> [drool](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/drool)
>   1 : saliva trickling from the mouth
>   // wipe the *drool* from his chin
>   (M-W)

It's uncountable, so notice the difference in the example:

> There was **drool** dangling from her chin.

Answer (score 1):

**Globule** is a fun word for this:

> a tiny globe or ball especially of a liquid—[MW](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/globule)

Example in use (from a gross story):

> The man looks into the camera and smiles before releasing the globule of spit from his mouth, not once but TWICE.—[Daily Mirror](https://www.mirror.co.uk/news/weird-news/watch-disgusting-footage-barber-spitting-5176862)

Answer (score 1):

***Dribble*** is a word describing a thin stream of liquid. With no other context, the liquid is usually assumed to be saliva, but it can be used to describe other liquids. The word can be used as a verb to describe liquid flowing (often out of the mouth), or as a noun to describe the liquid itself.

Answer (score 0):

I would refer to a drop or droplet of saliva hanging from someone's mouth, though (especially since 2020) it's common to hear droplets of saliva referred to for the liquid that sprays from a person's mouth as they talk or cough.

"imagine a shaved gorilla with his knuckles dragging along the ground and a wide toothless grin, the occasional drop of saliva dangling from the side of his mouth" -- [What Planet Are You From, Kenneth M. Hood, 2016](https://www.bol.com/nl/nl/f/what-planet-are-you-from/9200000056493565/)

"In the lamplight , they could see a drop of saliva dangling from the corner of the owner's mouth , as he appeared to sleep" -- [The Day the Sun Died, Yan Lianke, 2018](https://books.google.com/books?id=ZkRnDwAAQBAJ&pg=PT124&lpg=PT124#v=onepage&q&f=false)

Alternatively, a trickle of saliva dangling from one's mouth, though that evokes a somewhat different shape and image:

"I stared listlessly at the computer, accomplishing nothing, my eyes bloodshot, a trickle of saliva dangling from my mouth," -- [Doubt is the Devil, Matthew Felix (blog post), 2021](https://thewritespot.us/marlenecullenblog/doubt-is-the-devil/)